# CGEventPost only working when application is debugged

Tags: macos, events, event-simulation

In my application i want to emulate key strokes. Therefore i am using the CGEventPost API.

```
CGEventRef keyEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, keyCode, down);
(*) CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, keyEvent);
CFRelease(keyEvent);
```

I build my project with CMake. Once built and executed, the typical permission dialog pops up and i can activate my application in the accessiblity tab.
Running the application again and having a breakpoint at the (*) location, emulates the wished key press. However if i start the application from console or remove the breakpoint, no key gets emulated. Does somebody know, what could be the cause of this?

The app should not be sandboxed and is not signed.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of privilege resolution issue with unbundled executables. Even though you’ve granted it keyboard access, macOS is behaving like you haven’t (note that certain privilege checks are bypassed completely if you run a debugging session – that must be why it works for you with the debugger attached). Does the executable show in Privacy and Security settings?

Comment: Yes this could definitely be. If debugging i also get the typical permission pop up which asks to add my application to the accessiblity settings. After doing that it works once and my application is listed there (in privacy & security > accessiblity). As i am new to macOS development, could you explain what "unbundled executable" means?
Also to test my application i tried to sign the executable with a development certificate (Signing: Development) and also with local certificate (Signing: Sign to run locally) but that didnt change anything either.

Comment: Bundles are regular Cocoa apps; basically just folders with the `.app` extension; but what they have, and separate executables like the one you get with CMake haven’t, is the `Info.plist` file containing, among other things, a unique bundle identifier. macOS relies on those IDs for certain things, and I’m guessing resolving privileges may be one of them. If that’s the case, it may be failing to grant your executable appropriate privilege simply because it doesn’t know it’s the same executable. Again, if that’s the case, there may be no workaround apart from bundling it as a full-blown app.

Comment: Just found out, accidentally, that you can embed the Info.plist into the executable itself. Never tried it, but [here](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-embed-info-plist-in-a-simple-mac-binary-file/512/2) is a discussion on how to do that with CMake. You’ll want to make sure your plist contains a valid string for the `CFBundleIdentifier` key.

Comment: Thank you! i will try the bundling and maybe also embedding it directly (which i tried already with an entitlesments.plist)